# When and how would MyISAM concurrent insert = always be a problem?

Tags: mysql, myisam, insert, concurrency, locking

I wish to set [`concurrent_insert`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert) to `always` on a MyISAM log table, so that [inserts wouldn't have to wait for selects to perform](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/concurrent-inserts.html) when there are some holes in the table.

We're talking about 10-20 inserts per second and quite rare but yet some selects on the log that could take around 10s. I don't want my 100-200 inserts wait for these selects.

My question is quite simple actually. Taken aside the hole not-always-being-filled concern, **when and how would it do any harm** ?

Nota Bene: I wouldn't use `DELAYED INSERT` as they are of the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` form.

Answer (score 1):

The only immediate harm I can think of is dealing with contention from the `UPDATE`.

Normal `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` commands execute a full table lock. Doing ON `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should work the same.

In addition, what if the row's size changes to the point that the row needs to be bigger that the row's original allocation because of increasing the length of a `VARCHAR` column? That would require writing the row to a new part of the MyISAM table.

The only exception to this concern is when the MyISAM table

- has no `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` fields
- has no `TEXT` fields, has `VARCHAR` fields but `ROW_FORMAT=Fixed`

The MyISAM table would probably have some contention issues if you have `TEXT` fields because of the lack of length control or possible overflow of data to handle no matter what the table's `ROW_FORMAT` is set to.

Comment: So you're telling me that, at worst, I'd still have contention on `UPDATE`s, when the `UPDATE` would enlarge the row. Sounds better than dealing with contention for each and every `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, right?

Comment: You are correct, provided `UPDATE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` commands are rare (or at least infrequent). There may still be a full table lock in those two instances.